# Create a zip archive in c++

Tags: c++, unix, boost, zip, gzip

Is there a way to create a zip archive with the full folder content or multi-files.

I actually looked the example on the web but each time it's a compression of file only based on a buffer like for example : gzip_compressor() or gzwrite()

I can't give a full path in input but only a file buffer. 
=> Then no folder compression nor multi-file compression ???

Please note that I would like to use zlib/gzip or boost (the only library i can link)

I think I missed something there...

Can you please help me ?
Marc.

Comment: The `gzip` functions in `libgz` are only for *compression*. Search for a library which can handle `zip` archives.

Comment: You might look up `libzip`.  It's a C library, but you can call it from C++.  http://www.nih.at/libzip/

Comment: what do you mean by "call it from c++" ? is it an external library ? Do you have documentation ? I can't find some on the website...

Comment: You can invoke C code from a C++ application.  There are many references on the net, such as this one: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mixing-c-and-cpp.html

As for libzip itself, it is an external library.  Read its man pages, starting here: http://www.nih.at/libzip/libzip.html  Click the other functions for their man pages.

Comment: do you want any command from unix for zip a folder or multi-files ?

Comment: Well, that's fine now. I finally call the shell using popen() methode and created my tarball/compression in this way.

Comment: using tar command also we can archive zip file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several libraries out there to handle zip files.  They use zlib for the compression, decompression, and crc32 operations.  You should look at [libzip](http://www.nih.at/libzip) and [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this will work.  If you are on a Unix environment you may have to run the Java version:

http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Comment: Is there a way to do it with zlib/gzip or boost only ?

Comment: I'm look for a method like compress with input a vector of buffer and output a single archive